# How to create Angular package, with reusable set of pages, routes?

Tags: angular, npm

I would like to create Angular packages as complete reusable set of pages, but I do not know if is it even possible, and if it is, then what is the fundamental way/architekture to implement it.

Say I have an Angular app. Then I install npm package '@myuilibrary/account' and 11 pages what are defined in 11 components, and are in the module account become available in my app, under the route /account

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is [create a library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).

Create your library of components/services/etc, then import it into your various projects. I wouldn't set up routing in this shared library. Instead, let your other projects simply import your shared module and use the components where they're needed.